# All alerts on all ids in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a few buttons pop different menus, but I can't seem to make my JQuery call it just once. This is an almost exact copy of the sample code in w3, but for some reason whenever I click in any of the buttons both pop up one after the other.

HTML:

```
<p id="Chombas"> Chombas </p>
<p id="Buzos"> Buzos </p>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js">
</script>
<script src="calc2.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready("#Chombas").click(function() {
      alert('CHOMBAS');
});
$(document).ready("#Buzos").click(function() {
      alert('BUZOS');
});
```

Please help!

Comment: What w3schools tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not a selector to be chained. Wrap your script in only a single `$(document).ready`, and then attach listeners accordingly:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#Chombas").click(function() {
    alert('CHOMBAS');
  });
  $("#Buzos").click(function() {
    alert('BUZOS');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="Chombas"> Chombas </p>
<p id="Buzos"> Buzos </p>
```

Comment: It should also be noted that as of version 3.0 the `$(document).ready(fn)` form [is deprecated](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function) in favor of `$(fn)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#foo').click(function(e) {
        alert('foo');
    });

    $('#bar').click(function(e) {
        alert('bar');
    });
})
```

Try replace with this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#button-nav').on('click','p', function (evt) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-nav">
    <p id="Chombas"> Chombas </p>
    <p id="Buzos"> Buzos </p>
</div>
```

You can try this to avoid write duplicate code